# promise all convert the result into an object

Tags: angular, promise

I'm using promise.all in my resolver, it works, but now, I don't want an array of promises but an object, but I can't find how to do it.

This is my try:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any> {

  return Promise.all([
    this.service1.getAll(),
    this.service2.getAll(),
    this.service3.getAll()]
      .map((result) => {
        first: result[0],
        second: result[1],
        third: result[2]
      })
  ) 
}
```

As you can see I want to convert the array into an object with key - value

how can I map the result to get an object instead the array?

Comment: What should the structure of that object look like?

Answer (score 11):

You can actually make use of [destructring in es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) here. Since your `Promise.all(...)` will resolve to an array with three items in it, you can have `[first, second, third]` as the parameter to the arrow function and JavaScript will pluck the items out of their place in the array and set them to variables with the corresponding names (ie. `first`, `second`, and `third` in this case).

Additionally, if you keep the variable name the same as the property name for the object you can use the short hand syntax below for creating the object.

```js
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.all([
        this.service1.getAll(),
        this.service2.getAll(),
        this.service3.getAll()
    ]).then(([first, second, third]) => ({ first, second, third }));
}
```

For reference, TypeScript transpiles the code in the `.then(...)` to the following es5 JavaScript:

```js
.then(function (_a) {
    var first = _a[0], second = _a[1], third = _a[2];
    return ({ first: first, second: second, third: third });
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with **ES6**:

```
const [x,y,z] = ['E','S','6'];
// x = 'E'
// y = 's'
// z = '6'
```

So you can use the same with ***Promise.all***

```
const [first, second, third] = await Promise.all([
  this.service1.getAll(),
  this.service2.getAll(),
  this.service3.getAll()
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any> {

 return Promise.all([
this.service1.getAll(),
this.service2.getAll(),
this.service3.getAll()]
  .map((result) => {
    this.allData = Object.assign({},result)
  })
 ) 
}
```

I hope this may help you... :)

[image: Data in object]

Comment: thanks but I want to change the keys, I mean I don't want 0, I want 'first'

Comment: @cucuru Sorry , I didn't get you. Can you please add your expected result ? I can be more clear on that

Comment: I want something like in the example { first: this.service1.getAll(), second, this.service2.getAll()}

Comment: `Promise.all()` returns a promise, not something you can call `.map()` on unless you are using a 3rd party library like Bluebird that adds `.map()` to a promise.  By default a standard promise does not have a `.map()` method.